# Multiprocessing with class functions and class attributes

Tags: oop, pandas, multiprocessing, python-3.5

I have a pandas Dataframe, that has millions of rows and I have to do row-wise operations. Since I have a Multicore CPU, I would like to speed up that process using Multiprocessing. The way I would like to do this is to just split up the dataframe in equally sized dataframes and process each of them within a separate process. So far so good...
The problem is, that my code is written in OOP style and I get Pickle errors using a Multiprocess Pool. What I do is, I pass a reference to a class function `self.X` to the pool. I further use class attributes within `X` (only read access). I really don't want to switch back to functional programming style... Hence, is it possible to do Multiprocessing in an OOP envirnoment?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible as long as all elements in your class (that you pass to the sub-processes) is picklable. That is the only thing you have to make sure. If there are any elements in your class that are not, then you cannot pass it to a Pool. Even if you only pass `self.x`, everything else like `self.y` has to be picklable.

I do my pandas Dataframe processing like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time


def worker(in_queue, out_queue):
    for row in iter(in_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        value = (row[1] * row[2] / row[3]) + row[4]
        time.sleep(0.1)
        out_queue.put((row[0], value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fill a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1e5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

    in_queue = mp.Queue()
    out_queue = mp.Queue()

    # setup workers
    numProc = 2
    process = [mp.Process(target=worker,
                          args=(in_queue, out_queue)) for x in range(numProc)]

    # run processes
    for p in process:
        p.start()

    # iterator over rows
    it = df.itertuples()

    # fill queue and get data
    # code fills the queue until a new element is available in the output
    # fill blocks if no slot is available in the in_queue
    for i in range(len(df)):
        while out_queue.empty():
            # fill the queue
            try:
                row = next(it)
                in_queue.put((row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]), block=True)  # row = (index, A, B, C, D) tuple
            except StopIteration:
                break
        row_data = out_queue.get()
        df.loc[row_data[0], "Result"] = row_data[1]

    # signals for processes stop
    for p in process:
        in_queue.put('STOP')

    # wait for processes to finish
    for p in process:
        p.join()
```

This way I do not have to pass big chunks of DataFrames and I do not have to think about picklable elements in my class.